# Why does this ffmpeg command line stop after ten minutes

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, command

I have this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.2.201/mpeg4/media.amp -vcodec vp8 -map 0 -t 60 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format avi -segment_list slist.txt "out%03d.avi"
```

It is reading a stream from an `axis 211a security camera.`

It works great for exactly ten minutes.  And them `FFPMEG` starts to report missing packets.

I've checked the camera and all the setting are correct to run continuously.  Also, if I view this feed from `VLC` it will run on for ever.

What is it that is stopping `FFMPEG` after exactly 10 minutes.

Comment: How many entries are in the segment list that is generated?

Comment: @shellter: the command line thrag's using specifies that the output should be segmented into 5 seconds long .avi files that have the prefix "out" followed by the integer index of the segment (upto 999) so I would think it's unlikely that any segment is bigger than 2GB.

Comment: How many entries are in out list is, naturally, determined by the segment size.  with 5 second segment I get 12 * 10 minutes = 120 segments in the list.

Comment: Just a little more additional info.

It seems some routers have a 10 minute timeout on TCP connections.  Not exactly sure how to verify that is what is biting me.  Or how to bypass this limit.

Answer (score 2):

Because of -t 60

‘-t duration (output)’
Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration. duration may be a number in seconds, or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.

Comment: Why would this cause problems after exactly *ten* minutes when 60 seconds is one minute?

Comment: Yes, I have the same question.  Any idea why -t 60 equates to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Because -t (time) is the duration of the output itself, playback time.